# Compare 2 numbers with up to 4 decimal points

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-2010, decimal-point, vba

I need to compare software versions that have up to 4 decimal places (14.7.3.13).  I have a static list I'm comparing values in a spreadsheet to.  If the values in the spreadsheet are >= the static number in my code I highlight the cell.
I'm having difficulty doing this.  I'm assuming my problem is the data type. I've declared my static values as variant.  I can change the data type in the spreadsheet but I don't know what data types to use in my code of on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you treat it as a standard text field and then split the software versions on the '.' character, then compare each individual "segment" of the version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you split the software versions on the '.' character, then compare each individual "segment" of the version? Something like this:

```
Dim value1() As String = version1.split(".")
Dim value2() As String = version2.split(".")
Dim greatestVersion As String

greatestVersion = value1 ' Start with greatest version as value1

If version1 = version2 Then ' Check to see if they are both the same
    greatestVersion = "BOTH THE SAME!"
Else If ' If not the same then determine the bigger value
For i=0 To value1.count
    If value2[i] > value1[i] Then
        greatestVersion = version2
    End If
Next




End If
```